# How do I insert a custom font into HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

So I wanted to insert a custom font to **HTML** and I can't quite figure it out. I tried doing this code down below but it did not work.

**Here is the file for the font I am trying to use.**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C_2kPmCHj60KyFKcxYiGuOkRO8p820Yt?usp=sharing

## Code

```
  <head>
    <div class = "center">
      <h1 style = "font-face: myFirstFont">
        Hi
      </h1>
    </div>
    <style>
      div.center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      @font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(candyshopregular-nobo-webfont.woff2);
        }
    </style>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line 3 of your HTML from:

`<h1 style="font-face: myFirstFont">`

to:

`<h1 style="font-family: myFirstFont">`

Comment: Note: your Google Drive link said "Access Denied", so I didn't try this with the same file you're using.

Comment: Try this one :https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C_2kPmCHj60KyFKcxYiGuOkRO8p820Yt?usp=sharing

Comment: Still not able to access nope. Did my answer work though?